# Creating a column with values based on order of unique values in another column

Tags: r, data-wrangling

[image: Table]

How to I create the number column as in the table attached, which look into the Admi_num column and check if its the first admission and then put a 1 in the number column and similarly put a 2 ,3 and so on values based on the administration_num column. Thank you

Comment: You need `data.table::rowid(PatID)`

Comment: or `dplyr::row_number()`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
df1$Number <- rowid(df1$PatID)
```

Answer (score 1):

If say your data name is `df`, this base R way should yield similar results

```
ave(df$PatID, df$PatID, FUN = function(x) seq_len(length(x)))
```

Comment: another way is`with(df, ave(seq_along(PatID), PatID, FUN = seq_along))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. :), next time I'll remember this instead